# Condition for existence of a unique solution for a desired variable in a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Consider a system of linear equations of the form
$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{L\times K}, \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{L}, \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{K} $$ with $L$ variables $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_L \in \mathbb{R}$ and $K\leq L$ equations.

We are interested in finding a solution for a single variable $x_l$. Is there an explicit condition for existence of a unique solution for this variable?

Example: if
$x_1+2x_2+3x_3=3$ and
$2x_2+3x_3=2$, 
then there exist a unique solution $x_1=1$ for the variable $x_1$, and we cannot find unique solutions for the other variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming that there is at least one solution, the condition is that the null-space of $A$ has zero projection on the $l$'th coordinate. In other words, any vector in the null-space of $A$ must have its $l$'th component equal to 0. In your example, the null space satisfies this as it is spanned by $(0,1/2,-1/3)$.

This must be the case since $Ax=b$ has solution $x$, then so is $x+u$ where $u$ is in the null-space.

Comment: Can this condition (any vector in the null-space of A must have its l'th component equal to 0) be written explicitly in terms of matrix A?

Comment: @mohsenh01: not really, you have to solve for the null-space.